# Can't REMOVE white space between MENUBAR and HEADER,

Tags: css, wordpress, menu, header, whitespace

I've been trying to remove the white space between my menubar and headline image of the "Our Philosophy" only. I am using the "Rocked" theme on Wordpress.

My website link is: https://www.northerncoastal.com/our-philosophy/

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! We like people who ask questions to post the relevant code (and no more than what's relevant) directly in the question, for posterity. Please review https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for more guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

Set .main-content padding to 0 !important.

Answer (score 0):

The white space is caused by : `.main-content{ padding: 80px 0;}`

You need to set the padding to 0. If this is a preset theme though, you might need to make sure that you have the right page layout set for the home page.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove padding from following code:

```
.main-content {
    padding: 80px 0;
}

.hentry {
    padding: 30px;
    margin: 0 0 30px;
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

Or you can change your code to following:

```
.main-content {
    padding: 0;
}

.hentry {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 0 30px;
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove two things from your style.css :

First :

```
.main-content {
/* padding: 80px 0; */
 }
```

Second :

```
.hentry {
/* padding: 30px; */
margin: 0 0 30px;
background-color: #fff;
}
```